# How to do paging in UWP ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, win-universal-app

So I have a horizontal listview with items. I calculate the size of these items so that exactly 6 are visible at once.

Now I would like that when the user swipes left or right, it scrolls, and when the scroll starts to decelerate, that it goes to the nearest page (like the home screen of any iOS or Android device).

Is there a way to do this simply? I mean easy like setting a property on the listview? Or do I need to calculate all these things myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the functionality you mention (scroll left or right between pages) is very similar to Pivot control. You may consider having a Pivot control with individual ListView's or GridView's, and you can populate this control at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination of List view could be an overhead. I am not aware of any easy way for that. As mentioned by Dmitri, use pivot or flip view to make it easy.